# ionic doesn't run on device

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run an Ionic exemple app, but i'm just no able to make it works with run and emulate.
I'm able to run some Android Studio examples in my device without problems and able to run it with `$ ionic serve` but when I try to run it with `run android`, the answer is this:

```
$ ionic cordova run android --device
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[13:54:25]  build dev started ... 
[13:54:25]  clean started ... 
[13:54:25]  clean finished in 8 ms 
[13:54:25]  copy started ... 
[13:54:25]  deeplinks started ... 
[13:54:25]  deeplinks finished in 59 ms 
[13:54:25]  transpile started ... 
[13:54:31]  transpile finished in 5.63 s 
[13:54:31]  preprocess started ... 
[13:54:31]  preprocess finished in 1 ms 
[13:54:31]  webpack started ... 
[13:54:31]  copy finished in 6.18 s 
[13:54:39]  webpack finished in 8.41 s 
[13:54:39]  sass started ... 
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[13:54:41]  sass finished in 1.72 s 
[13:54:41]  postprocess started ... 
[13:54:41]  postprocess finished in 24 ms 
[13:54:41]  lint started ... 
[13:54:41]  build dev finished in 16.39 s 
> cordova run android --device
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
chmod: File not found: /Users/<me>/cutePuppyPics/platforms/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

sed: no such file or directory: /Users/<me>/cutePuppyPics/platforms/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

(node:10706) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /Users/<me>/cutePuppyPics/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
(node:10706) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?

[13:54:46]  lint finished in 5.50 s
```

running `cordova requirements` it shows me that I have gradle installed:

```
$ cordova requirements
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-27,android-26,android-24,android-23
Gradle: installed /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gradle/bin/gradle
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your gradle configuration needs to be updated so you can try this.

```
npm install -g cordova
cd my_project
cordova platform update android
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete all .gradle files from project dir.
2. add android platform. If exist rm it and add again. cordova platform add android@6.3.3
3. try cordova build again.
4. have success

Comment: I wasn't able to install cordova-android 6.3.3, is it important? I'm installing cordova-android@~7.0.0. I tried to do what you've said with this version, but still having the same error.

Comment: You need install android 6.3.3, not a cordova. I'm using 7.1.0 of cordova